# Why does not work wpide_save_file&filename=/?

Tags: python-3.x, function, azure-functions

my site POST `xxx.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`

```
Host: xxx.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: xxx.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpide
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Length: 1
Origin: xxx.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie:
```

```
post:action=wpide_save_file&filename=/uploads/2021/01/totoyyshg.phP&_wpnonce=844da21b3a&content=getlwn
```

I can send data in the livehttp header but the python does not fulfill the post function

my py code:

```py
LH = {'Host': 'xxx.com',
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0',
       'Accept': '*/*',
       'Accept-Language': 'tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
       'Referer': 'xxx.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpide',
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
       'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
       'Content-Length':'109',
        'Origin':'xxx.com',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Cookie': ''
         }
filj={"action":"wpide_save_file","filename":"/uploads/2021/01/totoys.phP","content":"getlwn"}
resultwya = req.post('xxx.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',headers=LH,data=filj,timeout=25)
```

why not post python?

Answer (score 0):

**This code how post python code:**

```py
wpide_save_file&filename=/uploads/2021/01/totoyyshg.phP&_wpnonce=844da21b3a&content=getlwn

my convert {"action":"wpide_save_file","filename":"/uploads/2021/01/totoys.phP","content":"getlwn"}
```

and post not work